# Error while modifying the color of pixels in a bitmap image with c#

Tags: c#, xamarin, bitmap

I have this code in which I try to modify the color of the pixel (x,y). I want to just get the Color given by Color.White - the color of the pixel (x,y)

```
  Bitmap  mPlan;
  for (int x=0; x < mPlanWidth; x++)
            {
                for (int y=0; y < mPlanHeight; y++)
                {
                    if (mPlan.GetPixel(x, y) == Color.White)
                     mPlan.SetPixel(x, y,  Color.White - mPlan.GetPixel(x, y));
                }

            }
```

But I have an error in the level of **Color.White - mPlan.GetPixel(x, y)** which tells me *impossible conversion of int to Android.Graphics.Color*

I Tried to convert all the colors to int using the Argb

```
   mPlan.SetPixel(x, y, System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(System.Drawing.Color.White.ToArgb()- mFloorPlan.GetPixel(x, y))   );
```

But the methods TpArgb are given only by the assembly **System.Drawing** and SetPixel take as third parametre a color of  Android.Graphics So I have this conflict of types.

Comment: Because `Color.White` is a Color object and `...GetPixel(x,y)` is not. That would be like me saying `object - 5` should actually equal an integer.

Comment: I know .. I want to just get the Color given by Color.White - the color of the pixel (x,y)

Comment: I think my answer does that. It works with two colors, I didn't actually try it with a Bitmap.Getpixel() though.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap bc;
Color color = new Color();
color.R = Color.White.R - bc.GetPixel(x, y).R;
color.G = Color.White.G - bc.GetPixel(x, y).G;
color.B = Color.White.B - bc.GetPixel(x, y).B;
bc.SetPixel(x, y, color);
```

Generate new color by setting the RGB value of the new color.

Comment: Thank you but It doesn't work I don't know why it gives me an int with bc.GetPixel(x,y)